# Using ProcessBuilder to get output of a command hangs after some time

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm using ProcessBuilder to execute commands and get the output.  This works pretty well, but after some time it just hangs and I can't see where I'm going wrong here.  I would love to see a **final** answer for executing commands with ProcessBuilder that returns the results and doesn't leave me with a ton of open file descriptors that eventually causes my commands to hang.

```
    // Send command, get response
    public static String command(String cmd) {
        String out = "no response";
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/system/bin/sh", "-c", cmd);
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process process = pb.start();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder response=new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line + "\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            if (response.toString().length() > 0) {
                out = response.toString().trim();
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            out = "Error: "+ e.toString();
        } 
        return out;
    }
```

Comment: It's not waiting for input?

Comment: Are you sure that running this command outside java prints results?

Comment: The commands I'm sending to it are things like "ifconfig usbnet0".  The results print immediately so I didn't assume I would have to use a thread to process the results.  After boot, everything works great for the first 4 or 5 runs and I get my results no problem, but then the commands start hanging, which causes the whole rest of my java program to simply not execute.

Comment: @ChrisH. how about adding 'process.waitFor();' just after the while loop it will properly wait for the process is terminated

Comment: I had process.waitFor() in there originally and thought that's what was hosing it up.  I re-added it right after the while() loop and did some testing this morning... no change. :(  It works for awhile, then stops working after about an hour.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I'm starting to think that there is nothing wrong with this code and instead there is another piece of my program that is taking up all of the file descriptors which then makes it impossible to run the commands I'm issuing.